# sizeof(structure) show wrong size in watch window in vs2013

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, gdb, sizeof

I don't understand why my code returns the value of the `sizeof` operator it does.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
        short x;
        short y;
}XY_T;

typedef struct{
        XY_T af[960];
        int top;
        int dummy1;
        int dymmy2;
        int dymmy3;
}STACK;

void func()
{
    int size = sizeof(STACK);
}
```

IDE: vs2013

OS: Windows 7

CPU: Intel i7

When I run my code with debug mode without optimization option, the variable `size` has a value of 3856, but but the watch window shows `sizeof(STACK)` with a value of 3844.

### Tested with gcc (version 5.4.0 20160609, Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) and gdb (version Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.5) and run on Linux pc1623754 4.15.0-64-generic #73~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 13 09:56:18 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have gotten answer by myself. 
It was intellisense problem.
Thanks for all of you guys.

Comment: How can you even add a compile-time constant to the watch window? That wouldn't make much sense in the first place.

Comment: I see 3856, as expected.  You can only get 3844 without the "dummy" members.  So you are probably debugging an older version of the source code.  Smells like a DLL Hell problem.

Comment: @Lundin, thanks for your answer first. So you say i should not check the sizeof(structure) result in the watch window?. In this case Why i get the proper result for other case(i mean, i have checked sizeof(structure) result using watch window). Could you explain me?

Comment: @Hans Passant, thanks for your help. But i have cleaned my project several times. I even re-run vs2013 and try again but i get the same result.

Comment: Declare a variable of type `STACK` and using the watch and the memory window (I do not know its exact name), see exactly which data goes to which place. It may happen that there are some alignment issues / padding bytes, or something else.You may want to get the `sizeof()` of the other struct members as well, for a better understanding.

Comment: @virolino, thanks for the help. I have tried what you said and i cannot see s32_dummy1,2,3 in what window. But, when i check the sizeof(STACK) result i run time using printf(“%d”, sizeof(STACK));. It show me 3856 byte.

Comment: It might also happen that the size is counted differently by the different tools: compiler, linker, debugger... Maybe some of them count only the useful bytes, while others might count the entire memory occupied, including embedded padding. The type itself cannot have alignment / padding issues, but a variable definitely can.